# Python Class File to List

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm doing a project that I have to create a class that going to read information in a file like the one below, and put it in a list. 
Each value in the list have to assign to a variable (name = 'Guillaume Dutroux')

> Day: 2019-01-12
>   Time:
>   09:00
>   Company:
>   iCageDoree
>   Clients:
>   Guillaume Dutroux, london, 2019-03-12, 13:30, 55, 4*, plumbing, 4h00
>   Jose Quesada, madrid, 2019-03-12, 10:00, 30, 2*, refrigerators, 5h15
>   Martin Wyne, london, 2019-04-30, 19:45, 105, 3*, wifi, 0h30

```
class ReadClients:
def __init__(self, fileClients):
    self._fileClients = fileClients

def readClients(self):
    with open(self._fileClients, "r") as file:
        for i in range(7):
            file.readline()
        self._clientsData = []
        for line in file:
            name, city, date, time, maxValue, minRep, domain, timeWork = line.strip(" ").split(",")
            self._clientsData.append(Clients(name, city, date, time, maxValue, minRep, domain, timeWork))
            self._nameCl = name
            self._cityCl = city
            self._dateCl = date
            self._timeCl = time
            self._maxValueCl = maxValue
            self._minRepCl = minRep
            self._domainCl = domain
            self._timeWorkCl = timeWork
        return self._clientsData
```

My code above is returning me:

```
[<clients.Clients object at 0x01B77170>, <clients.Clients object at 0x01B77230>, <clients.Clients object at 0x01B77310>]
```

and I don't know why.
Hope you can Help me.

Comment: You are appending class object in the list. So what's wrong? What do you expect it to return?

Comment: Tell us what is your expected output. That way it becomes easier for us to help you

Comment: I want it to return something like that, [['Guillaume Dutroux', ' london', ' 2019-03-12', ' 13:30', 55, 4, 'plumbing', ' 4h00']])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a small example of how you can play around with `__repr__`

```
class my_class:
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.name=name
        self.age=age

    def __repr__(self):
        return "(name="+self.name+', '+"age"+str(self.age)+")"

my_list = [my_class('a',1),my_class('a',2)] # [(name=a, age1), (name=a, age2)]
```

Comment: Thank's, that solves part of the problem, but the other thing is how i'm going to assign the values of the file to the self?